# VS 2019 C# console netcore 3 app not debugging

Tags: .net-core, x86, visual-studio-2019

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18362

IDE: Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Version 16.3.6

NET Core version: 3.0.100 Commit: 04339c3a26

**What to do:** Create simple .NET Core 3 console app in VS2019, switch target platform to x86 and press "F5".

### Then 2 options:

1. .NET Core 3 any versions installed in system (all combinations of x86, x64, both). Environment variable "path" for x86 moved up and "dotnet --info" shows that it targets x86 version:

**Error:** `The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[18492] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081).`

*P.S. In this case this error also shown when switched to x64 target platform. But everything works good when run as AnyCPU.*

2. Any version of .NET Core installed and environment variable for x86 version removed of moved below x64 version

**Error:** IDE can't find x86 version of dotnet.exe in Program Files (x86)

**Infos for both x86 and x64 versions of dotnet:**

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x86
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Have to say that x86 version of compiled console app works good if you launch exe file. Just can't launch it in debug from VS 2019. If switch to AnyCPU/x64

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.8) and got a similar error when trying to debug with target x86 (but a netcoreapp2.0 project):

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 40168) exited with code -532462766. 
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options- 
>Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

If I remember right, this was working out of the box with Visual Studio 2017 and after installing VS 2019, VS 2017 also started to behave the same. It's ridiculous that VS cannot detect the target platform and launch the correct dotnet.exe accordingly.

Fortunately the fix is quite easy, add this setting to your project:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunCommand Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So when debugging, if your current target is x86, it will use **C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe** and for others (default setting) it will use **C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe**

Of course you should first ensure you have a .NET Core X86 SDK.

For a more detailed setting (more conditions), see here:
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7532#issuecomment-330706524

Though, the simple setting above works well for debugging both x86 and AnyCPU.

Comment: I'm hitting an error even with that setting. I have x86 SDK and Visual Studio runs dotnet.ext from Program Files (x86), my project target platform is x86 and i'm still have this: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 52324) exited with code -2147450751. and output from Debug is: The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[52324] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081).

Comment: As well as the debug log in the output window, look at the test log in the output window.  This shows more info and links to solutions.

Answer (score 0):

for me happend  the same error, was because the parent folder name  was "c#" and another folder inside of it that contains the c# project, the name was "month 9", so i renamed it the "c#" folder to "csharp" and the "month 9" to "month9" and then a ran the project again and worked it.

example with error:
c# >
month 9 >
"project here"

example fixed:
csharp >
month9 >
"project here"